# Asp.net MVC multiple fields in dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list generated by a create scaffold that shows the first name of clients from the data base.

the view looks like this

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ProgramClientTbl</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientId, "ClientId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("ClientId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the controller looks like this

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ClientId = new SelectList(db.ClientsTbls, "Id", "FirstName"); 
        ViewBag.ProgramId = new SelectList(db.ProgramTbls, "Id", "Program");
        return View();
    }
```

Is there a way to add "LastName" to the dropdown list as well so more than one field is being shown?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know that this is an old question but I had the same problem and found this page before eventually figuring it out myself.

Here is the correct answer:

Controller:

```
var clients = db.ClientsTbls
    .Select(s => new
        {
        Text = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName,
        Value = s.clientId
    })
    .ToList();

ViewBag.ClientsList = new SelectList(clients, "Value", "Text");
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClientID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ClientsList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to update your model:

```
public class Teacher
{   //...
    public string PaternalName { get; set; }
    public string MaternalName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //... your others columns.  Add something like:
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return String.Format("{0} {1}, {2}", PaternalName, MaternalName, Name);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

THEN YOU ONLY HAVE TO:

ViewBag.CodigoDocente = new SelectList(db.Docente, "IDteacher", "FullName");

Comment: ViewBag.TeacherCode = new SelectList(db.Teacher, "IDteacher", "FullName");

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/64c3e38e-d612-4ba3-9707-ccfdc11fe6e7/cargar-dropdownlist-con-varias-columnas-de-base-de-datos?forum=aspnetmvces

Comment: You can add the corrections you mention here in your comments inside your answer using the "edit" link on the lower left corner of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `FirstName` and `LastName` properties

```
var clients = (from c in db.ClientsTbls
  select new SelectListItem { 
    Text = m.FirstName + " " + m.LastName,
    Value = m.ID.ToString()
  });
ViewBag.ClientsList = new SelectList(clients); // but better to assign this to a property in your view model
```

Then in your view

```
@Html.DropDownLstFor(m => m.ClientID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ClientList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: I tried to do the solution provided above, however all of the options in the drop down list say "System.web.mvc.selectlistitem" and not the actual values in the select list item. Any further suggestions?

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong because this should work fine

Answer (score 2):

sorry i can't add comment on Jason and Stephen Answer, but I tried to combine answers from JasonBlufire and Stephen Muecke, and it's worked.

```
var clients = (from c in db.ClientsTbls
  select new SelectListItem { 
    Text = m.FirstName + " " + m.LastName,
    Value = m.ID.ToString()
  });
ViewBag.ClientsList = new SelectList(clients,"Value", "Text");
```