# ASP.NET MVC DropDown list with multiple properties in multiple rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Complementary to this question [Asp.net MVC multiple fields in dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337533/asp-net-mvc-multiple-fields-in-dropdown-list).

How can I write multiple properties in a `DropDownList`?
I tried to use `"\n"` and `Environment.NewLine`, but it didn't work.

Example with `"\n"`:

```cs
var ground = db.database
    .Select(s => new
    {
        Text = s.Adress + "\n " + s.Home + "\n" + s.Number,
        Value = s.ID
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: The answer in the post you are referencing is quite clear: `Text = s.Adress + " " + s.Home + " " + s.Number`. Why you don't want to use it? And what exactly **_didn't work_**?

Comment: @Victor If I am understanding OP correctly, they want it so they can line break in the `select`. not add spaces